# Setting return value in columnmajor crashes in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

When I run this methode the program crashes either when I access the returnvalue of `M_k` or when the program finishes. The similar code did work when I only used rowmajor storage. If I comment out the line `*M_k = temps;` it works as well, but of course I want the returnvalue

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::ColMajor> Matrix_CM_t;
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> ESMatrix_t;
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor> ESMatrix_CM_t;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> Vector_t;

/* M_k = M(I(1:k),:) */
void fill_matrix_from_first_rows_from_list(ESMatrix_t *M, Vector_t *I, int64_t k, ESMatrix_CM_t *M_k) {
    int64_t i;
    Matrix_CM_t temp = Matrix_CM_t(k, M->cols());
    ESMatrix_CM_t temps;
#pragma omp parallel shared(M,M_k,I,k) private(i,row_vec)
    {
#pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i<k; i++) {
            temp.row(i) = M->row(I->coeffRef(i, 1));
        }
    }
    temps = temp.sparseView();
    temps.makeCompressed();
    *M_k = temps;
}
```

`M_k` is initialized correctly before the method is executed
Can someone help me?

The code that calls the method I am using for testing

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Matrix_t temp;
    Vector_t *a, tempv;
    ESMatrix_t *AS, temp3;
    ESMatrix_CM_t *CS;


    tempv = Vector_t(3);
    tempv << 2,0,1;
    a = &tempv;
    b = &Vector_t();

    temp = Matrix_t(3, 3);
    temp << 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0;
    temp3 = ESMatrix_t(3, 3);
    temp3 = temp.sparseView();
    temp3.makeCompressed();
    AS = &temp3;

    CS = &ESMatrix_CM_t();

    cout << "A before " << endl << *AS << endl;

    fill_matrix_from_first_rows_from_list(AS, b);

    cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << *CS << endl;

}
```

Comment: Does the type `ESMatrix_CM_t` have a copy constructor.  Its probably failing because the type contains pointers you can't do a simple copy with.  As the function returns, the pointers within the type got out of scope and the memory becomes invalid.

Comment: Could you provide code which calls the method and reproduces the problem? Also, is the parallelization necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Btw: Could you compile with assertions enabled (i.e., without `-DNDBEUG`), it looks like `I->coeffRef(i, 1)` should be `I->coeffRef(i)` or `I->coeffRef[i]`.

Comment: I'd suggest to run the program with a memory checker like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to see where the memory gets corrupted.

Comment: @CodeGorilla All `Eigen::SparseMatrix` have a copy constructor

Comment: The parallelization is not part of the problem and the same code works if I replace all ESMatrix_CM_t with ESMatrix_t and all Matrix_CM_t with Matrix_t

Comment: `b = &Vector_t();` and `CS = &ESMatrix_CM_t();` seems strange to me. You take the address of a temporary. Why should `b` and `CS` be declared as pointers?